# application web on spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

I've some performance issues and i ve few questions for you :)
I created a scala application. This application calculate in live some statistics like the session ... from a cassandra database. I used spray as http framework to create my API . 
I used spark for calculating and map reducing results from cassandra. 
I put my application in spark with spark-submit.

Do you think this is the best way to develop an application in spark directly ? Or should i create one application (http) outside of spark , and call an other app only for computing data from cassandra with spark ?

I've 3 server ( 1 with 32G 8cores, 1 with 64G, 8 cores , and the last one with 64G 12 cores) for my tests (i know it should be better if i had sames servers in my cluster but i can t for the moment).
I use the standalone mode.
My configuration in spark_default.sh :

```
spark.deploy.defaultCores=28
spark.executor.memory=30G
```

And for the moment it slow, it take 9 seconds with 3 spark traitement :

- a map , a sortby and 1 collect (take 4s)
- sum operation (take 3s)
- sum operation (take 2s)

Just for a result like this :

> {"result":"success","list":[{"item":"1474236000","value":6},{"item":"1474239600","value":3},{"item":"1474243200","value":3},{"item":"1474246800","value":3},{"item":"1474250400","value":3},{"item":"1474254000","value":8},{"item":"1474257600","value":4},{"item":"1474261200","value":11},{"item":"1474264800","value":1},{"item":"1474268400","value":3},{"item":"1474272000","value":18},{"item":"1474275600","value":6},{"item":"1474279200","value":4},{"item":"1474282800","value":2},{"item":"1474286400","value":2},{"item":"1474293600","value":4},{"item":"1474297200","value":10},{"item":"1474300800","value":10},{"item":"1474304400","value":8},{"item":"1474308000","value":6},{"item":"1474311600","value":8},{"item":"1474315200","value":4},{"item":"1474318800","value":4},{"item":"1474322400","value":6}],"nb_session":137.0,"old_nb_session":161}

Do you have any suggestions for me? I don't understand why it s so slow :(

Thanks a lot

Comment: I think you should separate the Spark to application. Spark should act like a service. https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver may help.

Comment: Well, personally I would argue that it is not slow. These are not impressive latencies but Spark is not really designed for low latency jobs and you certainly don't make it easier. Why not work directly against Cassandra? Regarding separation it is certainly a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to work directly with Cassandra and [CQL](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_intro_c.html). If you cannot reflect everything in CQL you can always create a User-Defined-Function (UDF).

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCreateUDF.html

> By default, Cassandra 2.2 and later supports defining functions in java and javascript. Other scripting languages, such as Python, Ruby, and Scala can be added by adding a JAR to the classpath. Install the JAR file into $CASSANDRA_HOME/lib/jsr223/[language]/[jar-name].jar where language is 'jruby', 'jython', or 'scala'

One of the options to make low-latency Apache Spark solution would be to keep the data in Apache Spark (across multiple requests) and just query against cached data in each request (and skip the loading-from-cassandra part). This is non-trivial.